Fetch and Analyzing Data from Multiple Sources
I have this system I'm building where I need to fetch support chat data from multiple sources, then storing them in a database, then analyze them, I'm using ASP.NET and FastEndpoints as the Backend, and React as the frontend.
My question is what is the best approach to this, knowing that new sources could be added later, or removed, so I'll need to put all of this to consideration.

I'd create an interface to represent the functionality you want from your sources, eg.
public interface IChatSource
{
  Task<object> FetchData();
}

Then implement for each datasource type, eg.
public class SQLServerChatSource : IChatSource
{
        async Task<object> IChatSource.FetchData()
        {
            // add code to fetch from SQL Server - use 'await'
        }
}

You can then implement the interface again for each new source type and your analysis code can use any number of them and not care about the source type:
List<IChatSource> mySources;
foreach (IChatSource source in mySources)
{
  object sourceData = await source.FetchData();
}
// analysis code

